# Get value from parsed HTML using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

For a project to make communications clearer for a website, I have to pull the messages using regex (Why? Because the message is commented out. With normal document.getElement I can't reach the message. But with the Regex mentioned below i can.)

I am trying to get a value using this expression:

```
\s*<td width="61%"class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">(.|\n)*?<\/td>
```

How i use this expression:

```
var pulledmessage = /\s*<td width="61%"class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">(.|\n)*?<\/td>/.exec(htmlDoc);
```

The above expression gives me NULL when i console.log() it. My guess is that the htmlDoc format that i supply the regex is not working. I just have no clue how to make it so the value does get pulled.

What i use to parse HTML:

```
var html1 = httpGet(messages);

parser = new DOMParser();

htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(html1,"text/html");
```

The result I want to get:

```
<td width="61%"class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque"><b>D.</b> De: 
Information, Information. 
Information, Information
Para: Information
CC: Information
Alot of text here ............
</td>
```

I edited the above value to remove personal information.

html1 contains a full HTML page with the information required.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New attempt. Seeing how the `td` you need is commented out, remove all HTML comment delimiters from the loaded HTML file before parsing the document. This will result in the `td` being rendered in the document and you can use `innerHTML` to get the message content.

```js
const 
  documentString = `
  <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <body>
      <div class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">1</div>
      <div class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">2</div>
      <div class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">3</div>
      <div class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">4</div>
      <div class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">5</div>
      <div class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">6</div>
      <!--<div class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque"><b>D.</b> De: Information, Information. Information, Information Para: Information CC: Information Alot of text here ............</div>-->
      <div class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">8</div>
      </body>
    </html>`,
  outputElement = document.getElementById('output');

  debugger;
const
  // Remove all comment delimiters from the input string.
  cleanupDocString = documentString.replace(/(?:<!--|-->)/gm, '');
// Create a parser and construct a document based on the string. It should 
// output 8 divs.
parser = new DOMParser();
htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(cleanupDocString,"text/html");

const
  // Get the 7th div with the class name from the parsed document.
  element = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName('valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque')[6];

// Log the element found in the parsed document.
console.log(element);
// Log the content from the element.
console.log(element.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I believe i implemented it correctly, im getting data from element now but its not the text. this is my code now `var html1 = httpGet(messages);

        const
          // Remove all comment delimiters from the input string.
          cleanupDocString = html1.replace(/(?:<!--|-->)/gm, '');

        parser = new DOMParser();

        htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(html1,"text/html");`

Comment: `const
          // Get the 7th div with the class name from the parsed document.
          element = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName('valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque')[7];

        // Log the element found in the parsed document.
        console.log(element);
        // Log the content from the element.
        console.log(element.innerHTML);`

Comment: Say this is the 7th element: `<td width="61%"class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque"><b>D.</b> De: 
Information, Information. 
Information, Information
Para: Information
CC: Information
Alot of text here ............
</td>`. What do you need from this element?

Comment: <b>D.</b> De: Information, Information. Information, Information Para: Information CC: Information Alot of text here ............

Comment: You need the 7th element but you're getting the element at index 7 instead of 6. That strikes me as odd. When you say you're getting data from the element but not the text, what do you mean exactly. I now know what you're expecting (the value of `element.innerHTML`) but I don't know what the current output is.

Comment: With [7] I get the date: 2017-08-31T00:00:00 With [6] i get this: td width="14%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">Subject</td> aka the last <td> before the commented <td> its like it doesnt see the commented td.

Comment: Just noticed it doesnt remove the <!-- -->

Comment: Replace `htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(html1,"text/html");` with `htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(cleanupDocString,"text/html");`

Comment: Im getting the full <td> now so i guess its working fine now! I will further develop it tomorrow! Thank you very much for your patience and help! Even though i made some stupid mistakes!

Comment: Since we got it to work, can you mark this as the accepted answer. What do you want me to do with the other answer? Should I leave it or delete it?

Comment: Your choice, leave it or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a regex, native JS has your back!

```js
const 
  documentString = '<!doctype html><html><body><div class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">1</div><div class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">2</div><div class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">3</div><div class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">4</div><div class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">5</div><div class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">6</div><div class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">7<!--<b>D.</b> De: Information, Information. Information, Information Para: Information CC: Information Alot of text here ............--></div><div class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">8</div></body></html>',
  outputElement = document.getElementById('output');
  

function getCommentText(element) {
  for (var index=0; index<element.childNodes.length;index++){
    const
      node = element.childNodes[index];
    if (node.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
      return node.data;
    }
  }
}

// Create a parser and construct a document based on the string. It should 
// output 8 divs.
parser = new DOMParser();
htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(documentString,"text/html");

const
  // Get the 7th div with the class name from the parsed document.
  element = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName('valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque')[6];

// Replace the HTML of the element with the content of the comment.
element.innerHTML = getCommentText(element);

// The the inner HTML of the parsed document's body and place it inside the output  
// element in the page that is visible in the user agent. The 7th div should not 
// contain a number but the text that was originally in the comment.
outputElement.innerHTML = htmlDoc.body.innerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: When i implement this i get this error: Cannot read property 'childnodes' of undifined. I changed `const 
  element = document.getElementById('element');` to `const
          element = document.getElementsByClassName("valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque")[7];` the 7 is there because this is the sevened div that uses that class (i know its stupid to use the same class for multiple DIVS but thats how this website was already designed.

Comment: When it is the 7th `div`, shouldn't you use `getElementsByClassName("valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque")[6]`? I am assuming it is zero based like all other methods.

Comment: Yes it starts at 0 but i there are 8 in total, this one is the 7

Comment: In that case I would have to see your code and HTML in order to say why it doesn't work. It has to do with retrieving the element from the DOM.

Comment: its hard for me to explain my situation since i didnt fully develop this plugin. Im not fully sure how to implement the code, maybe im doing something wrong.

Comment: I think I may know the problem. You're using `document.getElementByClassName`, at this point have you already added `htmlDoc` document to the DOM? If not, can you execute `getElementByClassName` on `htmlDoc`?

Comment: Im stupid haha! I forgot to replace document with htmlDoc, the code is now not throwing any errors but the value is still undefined.

Comment: this is what element and htmlString puts out: element:<td width="9%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">undefined</td>
getPagesSource.js:109 String:undefined

Comment: I've updated the answer so it uses a parser and replaces the comment text inside the parsed document. Perhaps this will help you to determine what is going wrong in your code.

Comment: And how do i put the output in a variable? im sorry for so many questions, i got put on this project with 0 to none experience in advanced Javascript and there isnt really someone to help me (im an intern)

Comment: I'm getting confused on what your goal is. Do you want a method that returns the commented text, a method that places the parsed HTML file in the DOM with the commented text visible in the `td`, or something else all together? Which output do you want in a variable?

Comment: My total goal is to fill an array with all the data variables that i have, so client name, date the message was made, time the message was made etc. So i have all the other data, only thing that is left is the message. So i technically have everything but i need a way to grab the message from inbetween the comments. I am using a parser to use htmlDoc.get.....

Comment: The `getCommentText` method returns the message text, you can place this method result in a variable instead of assigning  it to `element.innerHTML` as it does in my answer.

Comment: I still get undefined, is this becaus the whole <td> with all the text is commented not just the text?

Comment: Okay, that was not clear from the question. Can you add the HTML you're parsing to the question? That would make this a whole lot easier.

Comment: i cant fully put it on this website because it could contain personal information. Let me grab 1 message and ill edit it so its internet proof :)

Comment: Added an image of the code that goes into the parse